# Oracle, what is Global Context (GLOBAL_CONTEXT)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms, oracle12c

I have read about DBSM_SESSION package, global user-defined application contexts and client identifiers. They are used to maintain database session with distributed application clients. But I don't understand what exactly is `GLOBAL_CONTEXT`

According to Oracle documentation

> GLOBAL_CONTEXT displays the values of global context attributes, which are accessible for the current session, based on the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER value. This view is similar to SESSION_CONTEXT, which lists the values of session (or local) context attributes set under the current session.

How does one add and removes attributes of GLOBAL_CONTEXT according to client identifiers? Why GLOBAL_CONTEXT coexists with user defined global contexts?

How is this

`SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_CONTEXT`

different from

`SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('GLOBAL_CONTEXT', 'attr_name') FROM DUAL`

Or is the latter even valid in the case of GLOBAL_CONTEXT?

Comment: Did you follow [the link to the security guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/using-application-contexts-to-retrieve-user-information.html#GUID-85E9C986-4D83-4DBB-9A2E-000E737F30D6)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't explain `GLOBAL_CONTEXT`